# Importing Bio python in a script is giving ImportError: No module named Bio.Seq

Tags: python, biopython

I installed biopython and used the test example provided in the documentation.

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq
my_seq = Seq("AGTACACTGGT")
print(my_seq)
my_seq.alphabet
```

In my command window if I type python then type in the example line by line everything works fine.

However if I type in the same lines in a `example.py` file and try to run the script I get:

```
ImportError: No module named Bio.Seq
```

Comment: Did you install biopython manually ?

Comment: yes, I built it and then installed it

Comment: What is the installation command used? Is it Linux platform or Windows platform

Comment: Maybe you have python2 and python3 installed, but biopython is installed only for one of the two?

Comment: I'm using windows. and it turns out that i have both python 2.7 and 3.5 installed. and i was under the impression that i'm using python 3.5 not 2.7 when running my scripts